# C, network programming - sockets. One socket for read, another for write - possible?

Tags: c, sockets

I wrote a simple client to communicate with my echo server in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[SIZE+1];
    int port = 6666;
    char msg[1000];

    int sockfd, recv_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &server_addr.sin_addr);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        printf("> ");
        fgets (msg, 999, stdin);

        if ((send(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg), 0) < 0))
        {
            close(sockfd);
            if (errno != 0)
            {
                perror("recv");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        if ((recv_size = recv(sockfd, buffer, SIZE, 0)) == 0)
        {
            close(sockfd);
            if (errno != 0)
            {
                perror("recv");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        buffer[recv_size] = '\0';
        printf("FROM SERVER: %s\n", buffer);
    }

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
```

}

And I'm wondering, if its possible to use one socket for reading only (on port, let's say 6666), and another socket (port 6667) for writing only?

How should I implement the server then?

Comment: if you need to restrict read/write - take a look at [shutdown](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html).

Comment: The `send()` and `recv()` don't necessarily send or receive the complete data in your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use two separate sockets bound to two different port on the server's side, no rocket science here. Question is: why would you like to do that?

Comment: For fun I guess:) But I'm worried about the socket blocking issue. Because I would like to use one for reading ONLY, and another for writing ONLY. And what about the server then?

Comment: `select`, `poll` and `epoll` are your friends. Also read about the reactor pattern: http://www.adamtornhill.com/Patterns%20in%20C%205,%20REACTOR.pdf

Comment: You're right to worry about socket blocking being an issue, it can be (because a thread that is blocked waiting for I/O can't do anything else; it can't even shut down cleanly when the user wants the app to quit!).  The solution to that problem is to use non-blocking sockets, though.  You can also use multiple sockets, of course, but that doesn't really solve the problem, because now you've got *two* sockets that are blocking for I/O.  (@alagner is right as well; once you're using non-blocking sockets, select()/poll()/epoll() will help you avoid spinning the CPU)